# How to use java applet in reactjs

Tags: java, reactjs, applet

I'm trying to integrate a specific java applet in my reactjs application. 
More over, I would like to make it run in a Dialog (using matelial UI).

I have a render function which works and when I click on a specific button, the Dialog is shown. The code concerning the applet part in the Dialog of my return() function is shown here :

```
<Dialog
      ref="dialogAction"
      title={this.state.dialogTitle}
      actions={customAction}
      actionFocus="submit"
      modal={this.state.modal}
      autoDetectWindowHeight={true}
      autoScrollBodyContent={true}
      contentStyle={styles.dialogMarvin}>

       <applet
        type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"
        width="540"
        height="480"
        codebase="./marvin"
        archive="appletlaunch.jar"
        code="chemaxon/marvin/applet/JMSketchLaunch"
        legacy_lifecycle={true}
        java-vm-args="-Djnlp.packEnabled=true -Xmx512m"
        codebase_lookup={false}>

        </applet>

      </Dialog>
```

When I run this code, the Dialog is shown as expected and the first time,  firefox ask me if I want to activate java (telling me that it's working so far). Watch the following picture: [applet ready to be loaded, but allowance asked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYXdA.png)

But once java allowed, nothing is displayed (only blank, look the following image: [once allowance granted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmnof.png)). If I check the code in the brower, some properties are missing. Instead of the original embeded code I have this one (missing archive, codebase and some other) :

```
<applet 
   type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"
   data-reactid=".0.$=12:0.0.2.2.0.$=10.0.1.0"
   height="480"
   width="540">
</applet>
```

Some inforamtions are displayed but I don't understand them yet.

Have you arleady try to emmbed an applet in your reactjs ? Have you some tips to give ? I'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: Don't use Java applets.

Comment: @SLaks your are not really relevant here, but thanks. Despite this, I have to use a third party java applet for the application I'm developping… any help would be gratefull. In the future, I will use only a javascript equivalent which will replace the applet, but waiting for a mature version, with all the options I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is picky when it comes to allowing random attribute names. So instead of injecting `applet` by using JSX, just set the innerHTML of the component instead. To do this, use React's `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
var dangerousMarkup = {
  __html: '<applet.... ' // the whole markup string you want to inject
};

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={dangerousMarkup}></div>
```

This is basically the same as setting `domNode.innerHTML = '<applet...'` with vanilla javascript, and React just let's the raw markup pass through without modification.

Docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Comment: Yes this is working but only outside a Dialog box (from material UI). If I put it into a dialog box, it's still blank. I don't undenstand why… I can deal with it without dialog box, but it would be better. I will continue to work on it.